# Trigger PTT on Baofeng UV-5R with Arduino

Tags: arduino, audio

A current project of mine is to have the Arduino Uno play an audio file off an SD card module. The audio file would come out of the Arduino and into a Baofeng UV-5R handheld transceiver. The first thing that needs to happen is Arduino would trigger Push-To-Talk(PTT) on the radio and then input the audio. I will post the pinout diagram of the 3.5mm jack. My question is can I send in a normal audio file or should I convert the file to a mono low bit rate and/or Hz file.

This is my first post here, so if a drawing or anything is need please let me know.

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

PTT is triggered when the PTT at the top of your diagram (MIC-) is connected to ground (SPK -). When shorted, only a few mA of current flows, so your can use a small transistor as a switch. For example, a '7002 would work. Connect the drain to the PTT (MIC-), gate to an arduino digital output, and the source to ground (SPK-).

By setting the arduino digital output high, PTT will be triggered.

Arduinos are generally bad at audio stuff, but you can find some PCM audio libraries or audio shields that can  help. The radio expects an audio signal, which as you noticed, arduino can't output without some hacking. So try to get the arduino to just play the file out to headphones. If you can get that to work, then you can use that output as the input to the radio.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this has been done with 8kHz mono WAV files.

Otherwise, you need an MP3 shield, but I doubt that is necessary considering the size of SD memory.

https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-audio-music-player

http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "send an audio file" as a stream of digital data.

You can transmit the audio from the file as an analog signal.

To do that, you will have to playback the audio file and convert it to an analog signal.

The bitrate doesn't much matter.  What matters (somewhat) is the audio bandwidth of the file.  In its simplest form "bandwidth" is the highest frequency present in the audio during playback.

Two-way radios like your Baofeng have a very "narrow" audio bandwidth.  They only pass frequencies between 300 and 3000 hertz.  That's about like a standard land line telephone.  Music sounds really crummy through it.  No bass, no treble.  Just mid-range.

You will need to play back the audio.  That's probably not something you'll do with your Arduino - it's too slow and doesn't have enough memory (or flash storage) to hold a useful amount of audio. It also doesn't have a real analog output.  What the Arduino software calls "analog out" is in truth a pulse train (see [PWM.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation))  If you trasmit that, it'll sound like somebody chopping up a speaker with a chainsaw.

You'll want a small record/playback module that you can trigger with your Arduino to playback your audio, and a relay module to activate the PTT.

You'll need to reduce the signal from the playback module with a couple of resistors.  The microphone input of your Baofeng expects some few tens of millivolts, and typical audio signals from a playback module can be a couple of volts.  Just using the audio straight to the microphone input will result in terribly distorted (extremely crappy sounding) audio.

---

I've intentionally not posted any details.  Your project is a long way from a point where there are details to be had.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do something similar to this with the exception that I am using audio generated by third party ham radio programs running on my test computer, such as MixW for SSTV. I've got an external USB sound card that will serve as the audio interface to the radio.

I initially attempted to capture the audio output by connecting the SPK+ to analog 0 of an arduino, and sound card ground to arduino ground. This looked like it might work until I connected and turned on the radio. More isolation is needed and I might re-visit that later.

The option I am looking at now is utilizing the serial interfacing in various ham radio programs and trying to come up with a way to take those same serial commands over serial to the arduino and performing the same PTT function. I managed to get this working using specific pre-built configurations in MixW. I was able to capture tx and rx strings and key the radio at the appropriate time. Right now the code just lights an LED or turns it off at the appropriate time, I have not built up the PTT circuit yet, but will probably just use a transistor or opto-isolator as that seems to be the simplest way ahead.

Unfortunately, switching to a different program and setting up the radio serial interface the same way, I seem to get very different serial outputs and in most cases, clicking TX causes the Arduino to reset. I'm hoping to try and find out more about what is happening here so I can more effectively capture the serial input from these various programs.

Just thought I would share my own experience in case anybody